# How to generate correct fake data in Laravel 8 with two foreign key?

Tags: php, laravel

I have these tables:

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name', 100);
       // .....
    });

    Schema::create('users_booking', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id_booking');
        $table->dateTime('created_at')->useCurrent();

        $table->primary(['user_id', 'user_id_booking']);
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('user_id_booking')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
```

This is my factory:

```
public function definition()
{
    $userId = 1;
    $userIdBooking = 1;

    while ($userId === $userIdBooking) {
        $userId = User::all()->random()->id;
        $userIdBooking = User::all()->random()->id;
    }

    return [
        'user_id' => $userId,
        'user_id_booking' => $userIdBooking,
        'created_at' => $this->faker->dateTimeInInterval('-90 days', '+ 90 days')
    ];
}




  User::factory(500)->create();
  UserBooking::factory(100)->create();
```

I am trying to do this, but sometimes I get error with primary key.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '95-131' for key 'users_booking.PRIMARY'

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Based on the `UserBooking` primary key constraints, you would need to validate `User::all()->random()->id;` is not conflicting with previous IDs already inserted in the `UserBooking` table.  `while($userId === $userIdBooling || UserBooking::where('user_id', $userId)->where('user_id_booking', $user_id_booking)->count() > 0)`

Comment: @WillB. it is not working :(

Comment: Different error message or same one? Are you creating multiple records at a time (bulk-inserts)? Since the [Eloquent ORM doesn't support composite primary-keys](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#composite-primary-keys), I recommend refactoring to a single column primary-key, with a unique constraint on the `user_id` and `user_id_booking` columns to reduce potential issues you may encounter.